Does anyone know which file contains the source code for the MFC class CWnd?
I know where the MFC header and source files are located (in my case, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc). The header containing the CWnd class is afxwin.h, does anyone know which file contains the source code?
I couldn't find any reference to a MFC class map in the Microsoft documentation, is there any such resource?

The MFC class hierarchy chart can be found (and downloaded from) here, though that's a different question and should be asked in a separate Q&A.

Well now I feel really stupid. I just tried searching "c++ mfc class hierarchy" and the top link was the same as yours. I've just spent 3 days using "c++ mfc class map" and found everything I'd ever want to know about message maps.

Searching for MFC resources is incredibly hard. You generally have to know the answer already to come up with the correct search phrase. And even then if you're just slightly off target searches come up empty. This is consistent across all popular search engines.

Hi Ben, there is wealth of implementation specific details for various MFC constructs found in the MFC Tech Notes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/technical-notes-by-number?view=msvc-170), which were written by the original MFC designers decades ago. MFC Message maps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn006-message-maps?view=msvc-170) being one of the topics.

The (majority of the) CWnd implementation is in the wincore.cpp file. It is located under %VSINSTALLDIR%VC\Tools\MSVC\<version>\atlmfc\src\mfc\ by default.
The implementation file is only available if you choose to install the MFC source files from the Visual Studio Installer.
